# Как задать значение ячейки QTabWidget в колонке связанной с QComboBoxDelegate

Tags: c++, qt5

Здравствуйте коллеги, сейчас осваиваюсь в QT5.10 вопросик такой:
Есть таблица QTabWidget где с колонкой связан делегат QComboBoxDelegate. 
В окне таблицы данные в ячейке отлично редактируются, а из кода изменить их значение не получается.
Делегат заголовок:

```
#ifndef COMBOBOXDELEGATE_H
#define COMBOBOXDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>

class ComboBoxDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QMap<int, QString> m_values;

public:
    ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    QWidget * createEditor( QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
    void setEditorData( QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
    void setModelData( QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry( QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void paint( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    inline QMap<int, QString>& values() { return m_values; }
};

#endif // COMBOBOXDELEGATE_H
```

Делегат реализация:

```
#include "ComboBoxDelegate.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QComboBox>

ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent):QItemDelegate(parent)
{

}

QWidget * ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor( QWidget * parent,
                                      const QStyleOptionViewItem& /* option */,
                                      const QModelIndex& /* index */) const
{
    QComboBox * pEditor = new QComboBox(parent);

    QMap<int, QString>::const_iterator i = m_values.constBegin();
    while ( i != m_values.constEnd() )
    {
        pEditor->addItem( i.value(), i.key() );
        ++i;
    }

    pEditor->installEventFilter( const_cast<ComboBoxDelegate*>( this ) );

    return pEditor;
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData( QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    int value = index.model()->data( index, Qt::EditRole ).toInt();
    QComboBox * cb = static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor );

    int idx = cb->findData( value );
    if ( idx < 0 ) return;
    cb->setCurrentIndex( idx );
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData( QWidget * editor,
                                    QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                    const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QComboBox * cb = static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor );
    int idx = cb->currentIndex();
    if ( idx < 0 ) return;
    int value = cb->itemData( idx ).toInt();
    model->setData( index, value );
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::updateEditorGeometry( QWidget *editor,
                                         const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                         const QModelIndex& /* index */) const
{
    editor->setGeometry( option.rect );
}
/**/
void ComboBoxDelegate::paint( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    int value = index.data().toInt();

    QString s = m_values[ value ];
    QVariant color = index.data( Qt::TextColorRole );

    if ( color.isValid() && qvariant_cast<QColor>(color).isValid() )
        opt.palette.setColor( QPalette::Text, qvariant_cast<QColor>(color) );

    opt.displayAlignment = Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignLeft;

    drawDisplay(painter, opt, opt.rect, s);
    drawFocus(painter, opt, opt.rect);
}
/**/
```

Привязка делегата к колонке таблицы:

```
ComboBoxDelegate *pModulatorDelegate = new ComboBoxDelegate(p_table);
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 1, "J3E(USB)" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 2, "J3E(LSB)" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 3, "A1A" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 4, "B8E" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 5, "A3E" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 6, "F1B" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 7, "H3E(USB)" );
pModulatorDelegate->values().insert( 8, "H3E(LSB)" );
p_table->setItemDelegateForColumn( MODULATION_TYPE, pModulatorDelegate );
```

Попытка задать начальное значение:

```
    item = new QTableWidgetItem();
    item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    /**/
    item = new QTableWidgetItem();
    item->setText( "J3E(USB)");
    p_table->setItem(i,MODULATION_TYPE,item);
    /**/
```

Если из делегата удалить метод paint(), то начальное значение вводится, но при ручном редактировании ячейки отображает вместо текстовой строки её номер (от 1 до 8 соответственно). Понятно, что причина такого поведения - строка

```
int value = index.data().toInt();
```

в методе paint(). Она перечитывая старые данные блокирует изменения. 
Подскажите, кто знает, как обеспечить ввод и вывод данных и из кода тоже, а не только с экрана приложения?

Comment: а если вместо `item->setText("J3E(USB)")` поставить `item->setData( Qt::DisplayRole, 1)` ?

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.